# How to write a loop that prints a table of values using a tab sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do here is create a table of values that displays the following as

```
N 10*N 100*N 1000*N 
1 10 100 1000  
2 20 200 2000  
3 30 300 3000  
4 40 400 4000  
5 50 500 5000  
6 60 600 6000  
7 70 700 7000  
8 80 800 8000  
9 90 900 9000  
10 100 1000 10000
```

My code is

```
var index = 0;
for ( index=0; index <= 10 ;index += 1)
{
    console.log(index)
}
```

This displays numbers from 0 to 10 down a straight line, however I'm still unclear how to use a tab sequence and to get each value to appear as "N*10". Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(index, index*10, index*100, index*1000)`?

Comment: I believe the tab sequence is as simple as `"\t"` as in `console.log(index + "\t" + index * 10 + "\t" ...);`

Comment: Since the behavior `console.log` is browser dependent, you may find that `\t` is necessary to ensure tabs in some browsers.  That said, if it's for development, (as `console.log` likely shouldn't be used as a user-facing interface), whatever works for you.

Comment: What about [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table)?

Comment: @DJDavid98 _"**Non-standard**: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."_ - I'd be warry of this as it doesn't seem like it'd be too reliable.

Comment: FWIW `console.log` is also non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

If your code doesn't need to run everywhere, you can use [`console.table`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#viewing-structured-data). It is available in Chrome, Firefox and Opera:

```
console.table([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(function(n){
  return [n, n*10, n*100, n*1000]
}))
```

[image]

`console.table` isn't available everywhere, isn't standard (nor is any part of the `console` API), but it is a very useful debugging tool.

Comment: No mention of the fact that console.table has a giant red warning saying  `This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. ` ?

Comment: Since `console.log` is also non-standard, I didn't see that as a problem ( especially as I listed the runtimes it works in).

Comment: Superficially yes, though I don't know if it's any more or less consistent than `log`.

Comment: True,  and apparently even `console` itself is non-standard.  Woe is us.

Comment: I've added some caveats.

Comment: [`console.table`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.table) is part of the [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 0;
for ( index=0; index <= 10 ;index += 1)
    {
    console.log(index + "\t" + index*10 + "\t" + index*100 + "\t" + index*1000)
    }
```

This should work :)